# Floating Refresh-Button for WebView

Tags: java, android, webview

I want to make a floating Refresh-Button for my WebView.
I did some research but I wasn't able to fix my problem.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    String url = "https://www.rtl.de/cms/sendungen/serie/alarm-fuer-cobra-11.html";
    WebView view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.WebView);
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.loadUrl(url);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            view.reload();
        }
    });
```

I also tried `MainActivity.this.webView.loadUrl("https://www.rtl.de/cms/sendungen/serie/alarm-fuer-cobra-11.html");` instead of `view.reload();` but there is always an error.

> Cannot resolve method 'reload()'

or

> Cannot resolve symbol 'WebView'

It would be very nice if anyone could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually just make an `Intent` and start your current activity as a new one. For example in your activity, make a button like this:

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Please tell me if it is ok.
Take care!

Comment: Thank you vermy much! I added MainActivity.this.finish(); at the end an it works great!

Comment: I'm glad it was ok. Np!